# Remove the "Dismiss keybard" key from a UITextView's keyboard on iPad

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitextview

I have a modal view that with a UITextView, and the user can enter some text (or not) and close the modal view. There is no point of dismissing the keyboard as it does not dismiss the modal view (this is on purpose), and the UITextView without the keyboard just looks silly.

Is there a way to hide or remove the "Dismiss keyboard" key from the keyboard?

Comment: Not sure that's a good idea. Maybe the user wants to dismiss the keyboard to look up something that it obscures.

Comment: @onnoweb the keyboard doesn't obscure anything, the modal view is designed that way. It really serves no purpose whatsoever to dismiss the keyboard in this case...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't hide or remove the key, but you can disable it using the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol:

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {

    return NO;
}
```

If UIKit forces the responder to resign despite the delegate (doubtful, but I haven't looked closely at the call stack), you can force the keyboard to stay up by observing the `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` and setting the  first responder back to the UITextView: `[myUITextView becomeFirstResponder]`

Comment: OK that is the best option if there is no way to remove it. can I change how it looks? maybe dim the opacity a bit so it will look disabled?

Comment: If you really, really want to remove it you can create a custom keyboard that mimics the stock one, but without the keyboard dismiss key. Look at the documentation for the `inputView` property. A word of warning though, this is not really practical since doing so essentially makes it impossible for the keyboard to be localized.

Comment: Alternately, I have seen some hacks that cast the UIKeyboard into a UIView and crawl through the hierarchy until they find the key they want and replace it with something else. This Apple dev forum post talks about it https://devforums.apple.com/thread/22301

Answer (score 0):

Protocol method doesn't help.
As Answerbot suggested one should listen to keyboard notification.

```
   - (void)onIpadViewWillAppear
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(showIpadKeyboard) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)onIpadViewWillDisappear
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)showIpadKeyboard
{
    [myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

This works and looks beautifully.